# number of edges in infinite graph

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, analytic-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory

Assume we have directed graph $P = (V,A)$, where $V$ -is a countable set (so, it may be infinite) of vertices and $A$ is a set of arrows (edges). The question: are there countably many edges, i.e. if $A$ is at most countable set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is countable, so is $V \times V$. If there are no duplicates (more than one edge between two nodes, resp. more than two directed edges), $A$ will be countable.

Comment: what if there are duplicates? and sorry I do not understand, how could it be more than two edges between two nodes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As long as the number of duplicates is a finite number with an upper bound, nothing changes. If the number of duplicates is an infinite set, anything can happen. Duplicates can arise depending on the world you're modelling. Say if the two nodes represent people and each edge represents them drinking coffee together, there can be loads of edges between every two nodes. (I drink coffee with my wife every morning). The upper bound would be something like 100 years * 365 day * 3 times/day